# Playing html video from rtmp URL

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3

I am trying to play a video in a page and I have following parameters

```
URL=rtmp://192.168.0.10/live
and a SWF http://192.168.0.11/file.swf?v=3
```

can anyone guide me on how to pass the rtmp to the  tag

Comment: check this: http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html

Answer (score -1):

If your SWF file is made by you, you can use the `ExternalInterface` AS3 class to provide bi-directional JavaScript communication. This will require modifications of your SWF file, however.

If you cannot do this, you'll need to ask your SWF provider to tell you how to do so.

If that's still out of the question, you could consider switching to a third-party player (jwplayer, flowplayer etc).

Comment: Cannot modify the SWF file.... if SWF file cannot be changed then using  third party will work ?

Comment: @AsadNauman: then you need to find a player that has a JS API. jwplayer has one.